# Сделать запрос так, как бы был сделан запрос с сайта пользователем

Tags: http, post, curl, postman

Есть страница, на которой вводятся данные, после нажатия на кнопку отправляется пост запрос с формой с заполненными данными.

Вопрос: каким образом можно имитировать отправку такого запроса со своими данными с помощью curl или postman? 
Ткните где можно прочитать про такой механизм.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так:

1. Открываете Инструменты разработчика - F12.
2. Переходите на вкладку Network.
3. Активируете галочку Preserve log
4. Нажимаете кнопку в форме
5. Ищете во вкладке Network запрос передачи формы
6. Нажимаете на эту строчку правой кнопкой
7. В меню Copy выбираете нужный вам вариант (например, Copy as cURL(bash))

Comment: Спасибо. Разобрался.

Comment: Не подскажите как это на питоне воплотить, чтобы скрипт параметры подставлял и делал запрос.

Comment: Не, это вряд ли. [Вот тут](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/) может что подходящее  найдёте.